# Some clever ways to segregate/separate these data rows

Tags: website-design

I've been playing around with borders but haven't seen that aesthetically pleasing look that soothes my soul.  Any ideas I can do here to make these rows of data flow nicely?

[image]

It's the Bootstrap framework, so each part is contained in a row, the text is `'col-md-9'` and the check box is `'col-md-3'`

Comment: The checkboxes aren't meant to be interacted right? They just inform services included or similar?

Comment: @Alvaro Correct just informative

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with most of the points @Rosiana shares. I would however:

- Put the checkboxes on the left side, where checkboxes usually are
- Align everything to the left

[image]

Comment: This positioning is surely better :)

Answer (score 4):

I think it will look better if:

- Checkbox icons have the same height as (or at least balanced) with texts;
- The text aligned to left (not centered), while the checkboxes to right;
- Expand the row height so the contents will look spacey and not too crowded;
- If you want you can separate each row with lines but lighter/thinner than the one separating your list with their title :)

Comment: Do not agree with checkboxes being the same size as the text, in Alvaro's example, why is demonstrated perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

As they can't be unchecked, I'd remove the box.

[image: Check list]

Comment: You got a point there but, in my opinion, the checkboxes checked reinforce the idea that there was something to be checked (if that makes sense).

Comment: It does, I think the QA is saying there's isn't something to be answered though.